# How to resize an input edit control of the TInputQueryWizardPage page item?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating a `TInputQueryWizardPage` page (by the `CreateInputQueryPage` function) and I would like to change the width of an input edit control of the item.

How can I do that? How to resize an input edit control of the `TInputQueryWizardPage` page item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit controls for the [`TInputQueryWizardPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputQueryWizardPage) are accessible through the `Edits` indexed property, so for example to change the width of the first item's edit you would write (indexing is 0 based):

```
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;
begin
  ...
  Page.Edits[0].Width := 150;
end;
```